Bigquery error about unable to cast timestamp string to a timestamp when trying to insert it
I am trying to insert this timestamp "2024-07-02T10:46:58.108707769" into a TIMESTAMP column in bigquery, but I get the error Query error: Could not cast literal "2024-07-02T10:46:58.108707769" to type TIMESTAMP, I do not understand what is wrong with this timestamp value as in some online tools it is valid, can someone help clarify?

The problem seems to be this: "BigQuery’s TIMESTAMP type supports up to microsecond precision (6 digits after the decimal point), but your timestamp has nanosecond precision (9 digits after the decimal point)."

Hi , I have posted an answer, if you find it helpful, please do consider upvoting and accepting it as per stackoverflow guidelines  helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

As per the Gcp documentation Up to 6 decimal places (microsecond precision) are preserved.
You can describe TIMESTAMP data types as either UNIX timestamps or calendar datetimes. BigQuery stores TIMESTAMP data internally as a UNIX timestamp with microsecond precision. Check this documentation  and  You can also  check this bigQuery not supporting milliseconds timestamps .As @ BugsOverflow already mentioned  you are using nanosecond timestamp , you have to convert to microseconds before the insertion.
